# Storing variables in SESSION array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have a variable which changes its value in every ajax request.
What I want to accomplish is to have a session array $_SESSION["tmp_arr"] and fill it with the values of this same variable. I dont want to overwrite the value of the $_SESSION variable, but append it in a array.
Which is the correct way to accomplish that?

Comment: first get exist value then replace with exist+new value

Comment: Why do I get a negative vote for this question? Downvoter thinks its better for the community to just see the correct answer and delete question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no such element in _SESSION or if it's not an array create a new one with the first/initial value. Otherwise append the new value to the existing array.

```
session_start();
[...]
if ( !isset($_SESSION["tmp_arr"]) || !is_array($_SESSION["tmp_arr"]) ) {
    $_SESSION["tmp_arr"] = array( $newValue );
}
else {
    $_SESSION["tmp_arr"][] = $newValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hyper-fast answer. Does exactly what I need. I will accept it asap.